# How do I implement a patch HTTP method in a custom rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I am trying to implement a patch method for my custom rest controller. The official Spring REST  tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) has most of the HTTP methods implemented except PATCH.

So how do I implement a patch method?

Comment: There is nothing different in PATCH method from PUT and POST. You have to see what you pass in your PATCH request and how you map the data in the Controller.

Comment: I answered the question above, please check it and if it is what you need - give me the answer, if not tell how we can help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
public MyDto createIt(@RequestBody myDto dto) {

    MyDto result = service.createC(dto);

    return result;
}
```

and dont forget to add 
@RestController to your class declaration or you need to setup @ResponseBody